# Rails issues with authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I  am  building  my  first  app  using  rails  and  i  am  struggling  to  give  an  account  to  each  user. Its  a  simple  app  where a  user  creates  a post  and  saves  it.  this  post  can  be  seen  on  index page.  Until  now  we  are  ok.  when  i  sign out,  i  register  a  new  user  and  i  log in.  when  i  go  to  the  index  page,  i can  see  what  other  user  has  saved. I  want  to  have  a  private  index  page  for  each  user  where  no one  can  see  what  users  are  saving in  their  app.  I  am  using  Gem 'Device" to  authenticate  my  app,  but  i  don't  know  how  to  make  private  their  account?  any  ideas?

Comment: This is not an issue of Rails per se.  Personally, I'd watch some Railscasts episodes and try to create your own user auth without Devise.  Devise even recommends that you don't use it if you're new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented authentication. Now you need to build authorization.
You have to define what data can be accessed by user.

Take a look at:

[CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)

Answer (score 0):

With devise authentication technique, after logging in the user you can write a clean piece of code to render the posts of the logged in user. You can use session data to do it. the `current_user` helper method returns the model class relating to the signed in user. With devise, it ensures after authentication that, it has the helper methods ready to be used. So, the error with no such user with that id can be avoided.

```
#web/controller/post_controller.rb
before_filter :authenticate_user!

def list
  @posts = current_user.posts
end
```

And then, use `@posts` in the list view to render the posts of the logged in user only.

```
<% @posts.each do |post| do%>
    <%= post.content %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi! I  think  i am  doing  it wrong.  Can  you  please  tell  me  what  to  code  on list view? It  is  giving  me  this  error: Couldn't find User with 'id'

Comment: I haven't used devise but if there's a login system in your application, there should be a sessions controller to manage sessions. Here the error is saying that there's no user with that id. Maybe the session controller hasn't saved the session variable of that user or, you are not logged in as a user if your session controller has the user saved. In the list view, you just need to print them all like `<% @posts.each do |post|>; <%= post.content %>; <% end >` it prints all the posts of a user. But the error is from the controller. Do let me know about your sessions controller.

Comment: I  dont  have  a session  controller in my app.  I just  have  Locks controller  and  Info Controller( static_pages Controller).  Gem  'Device' is  doing  perfectly authenticating  my  app,  but  not my privacy  of  users. This  is  my  app https://datainfk.herokuapp.com ;  if you  want  you  can  have  a look. please  let  me  know  what  part  of  my  code  do  you  need! Thanks

Comment: Ah ! I just found out that devise is so easy to implement. You don't need to write custom sessions controller to store current users data. it already provides you with a method called `current_user` which returns the current user who is logged in. So, you can use that to retrieve the data from the user who is currently signed in. If you have written the codes to have a one many relationship from users to posts, i.e one user has many posts, you can retrieve them. I am updating the answer with that helper method `current_user`.

Comment: But, you should cover the basics of authenticating the user first as a beginner. It can help you understand what actually your rails app does while registering and logging someone in or out. Follow the rails cast by Ryan Bates [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch) . Then, understanding devise will not be a headache. It's too easy I saw.

Comment: It  is  still  not  working! My  controller  is  LocksController.  By  def list  you  mean  the  def  index  in  my  controller??  Also  list  view  is  the  index view? I  have  a  one  to  many  relationship where  one  user  creates  many  locks,  and  locks  belong to  user.  when  i change  the  code  to  the  one  you  referenced  i  get  this  error :undefined method `Lock' for #<User:0x9b038e0> ....  I  reviewed  Ryan Bates cast  but  i  think  is  different  from  what  i  want...

Comment: What did you write ? I didn't find any code here so I assumed the names. By the way, yes, your index method is the list method here and list view is index view. Can you update your question with the controller code ? Your heroku app is the result. Is there any GitHub repo where I can find the code ?

Comment: Please let me know the problem. If it has been solved, tick the arrow mark and make it green.

Comment: I  am  sorry  for  the  late  reply! My  app  is  not  working  again! I  will  provide  the  GIT repo  to  you  as  soon  as  i  push  it. Thank  you  for  your  effort!